# Is there a way to protect data from being scraped in a PWA?

Tags: react-native, ionic3, progressive-web-apps

Let’s say I have a client who has spent a lot of time and money creating a custom database. So there is a need for extra data security. They have concerns that the information from the database could get scraped if they allow access to it from a normal web app. A secure login won’t be enough; someone could log in and then scrape the data. Just like any other web app, a PWA won't protect against this.

My overall opinion is that sensitive data would be better protected on a hybrid app that has to be installed. I am leaning toward React-Native or Ionic for this project.

Am I wrong? Is there a way to protect the data from being scraped in a PWA?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to protected data visible to browser client regardless of technology - simple HTML or PWA/hybrid app.

Though you can make it more difficult.

1. Enforce limits on how many information a client can fetch per minute/hour/day. The one who exceed limits can be blocked/sued/whatever.
2. You can return some data as images rather than text. Would make extraction process a bit more difficult but would complicate your app and will use more bandwidth.

If we are talking about a native/hybrid app it can add few more layers to make it more secure:

- Use HTTPS connection and enforce check for valid certificate.
- Even better if you can check for a specific certificate so it's not replaced by a man-in-the-middle.

I guess iOS app would be more secure then Android as Android is easier to decompile and run modified version with removed restrictions.

Again, rate limiting seems to be the most cost effective solution.

On top of rate limiting, you can add some sort of pattern limiting. For example, if a client requests data with regular intervals close to limits, it is logical to think that requests are from a robot and data is being scrapped.

Comment: Your points are valid. I am most concerned about scraper bots. I don't see how it is possible to scrape an app that is installed on the device. You could take screenshots, but that is about it.

Comment: They can sniff network and re-engineer your API and make requests using simple CURL or any programming language. Or decompile APK and run scrapping using your API library.

See my edit on rate & pattern limits.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Yes, I was thinking about implementing some sort of token scheme with the web services to make that portion secure. Suppose HTTPS and tokens were implemented properly, do you see any other issues with a native/hybid app in regards to data security? I will accept your response as the answer for now.

Comment: I am not a profi on security but I don't see big difference between native/hybrid app in terms of data protection. Checking rates/patterns per client on server side is most reliable way I believe. This is how it's handled by most data/API providers.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS encrypts the data being retrieved from your API, so it could not be 'sniffed' by a man in the middle.
The data stored in the Cache and IndexedDB is somewhat encrypted, which makes it tough to access.
What you should do is protect access to the data behind authentication.
The only way someone could get to the stored data is by opening the developer tools and viewing the data in InsdexedDB. Right now you can only see a response has been cached in the Cache database.

Like Alexander says, a hybrid or native application will not protect the data any better than a web app.